# Intersection of ideals is zero and quotients are noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

> Assume $R$ is a ring and $I_1,...,I_n\subseteq R$ ideals s.t $R/I_i$ is noetherian for every $i$, and $\bigcap_{i=1}^nI_i=\{0\}$, then $R$ is noetherian.

My attempt: I defined the natural homomorphism $\phi:R\rightarrow R/I_1\times\dots\times R/I_n: \phi(r)=(r+I_1,\dots,r+I_n)$. Since the intersection is the zero ideal, I then can say that: $R\simeq\{(r+I_1,\dots,r+I_n)|r\in R\}\subsetneq R/I_1\times\dots\times R/I_n$. I haven't learned modules - so the existing solution to this problem on this site doesn't help me.

How do I show that the right side of the isomorphism is noetherian? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816183. Since the OP looks for a solution without modules, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I'd actually recommend learning some stuff about modules at this point as it just makes a lot of things easier to understand in commutative algebra. Even the proof below basically mimics the proof in the other answer.

Comment: @RithvikReddy "Even the proof below basically mimics the proof in the other answer." - Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I show the case $n=2$, the general case is very similar.

Let $R$ be a ring with two ideals $I,J$ with $I \cap J = 0$ such that $R/I$ and $R/J$ are Noetherian. We want to show directly that $R$ is Noetherian. Since it was asked for a proof without module theory, the proof does not use the standard arguments from module theory (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816183/intersection-of-ideals-is-zero-then-r-is-noetherian)). But the arguments are basically the same, just written down in this special case here, which makes the proof somewhat clumsy in my opinion.

Let $\pi_I : R \to R/I$, $\pi_J : R \to R/J$ denote the canonical projections, and let $\pi := (\pi_I,\pi_J) : R \to R/I \times R/J$.

Consider an ascending chain of ideals $(K_n)$ in $R$. This yields an ascending chain of ideals $\pi_I(K_n)$ in $R/I$. Since $R/I$ is Noetherian, we may assume (after shifting the indices) $\pi_I(K_n)=\pi_I(K_0)$ for all $n$.

Now consider $L_n := \{y \in R/J : (0,y) \in \pi(K_m)\}$. Then $(L_n)$ is an ascending chain of ideals in $R/J$ (check this!). Since $R/J$ is Noetherian, we may assume (after shifting the indices) that $L_n = L_0$ for all $n$.

I claim $\pi(K_n)=\pi(K_0)$. In fact, let $k \in K_n$, and $\pi(k) = (x,y)$. Then $x \in \pi_I(K_n)=\pi_I(K_0)$, hence $\pi_I(k')=x$ for some $k' \in K_0$. Let $y' := \pi_J(k')$, so that $\pi(k')=(x,y')$. Therefore, $\pi(k-k')=(0,y-y')$. Hence, $y-y' \in L_n=L_0$, so that $(0,y-y')=\pi(k'')$ for some $k'' \in K_0$. Hence, $\pi(k) = \pi(k-k')+\pi(k')=\pi(k''+k')$, and we are done.

Since $\pi$ is injective, it follows that $K_n=K_0$ for all $n$.